# How to handle BDD / TDD duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, clean-up

Recently, @gnat proposed a duplicate where this is the source:

[What is the difference between writing test cases for BDD and TDD?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/what-is-the-difference-between-writing-test-cases-for-bdd-and-tdd)

and this is the target:

[Relation between BDD and TDD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111837/relation-between-bdd-and-tdd)

I agree that the answer to the lower voted question is much more thorough and complete than the answer to the higher voted question, and the target is slightly broader so it makes for a slightly better target, but it seems wrong to me to close such a highly voted question as the duplicate.

Perhaps the higher voted question with almost 100x the views should be made the target somehow, and then the answers merged from the other question into the higher voted one.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I guess my question back at you is, what is more important to the site in your opinion?  Having a high quality question with comprehensive answers that can be searched on, or having a more popular question with high view count?

Comment: @maple_shaft Both. That's why I'm thinking merge / edit may be better here than a simple VTC - dupe

Answer (score 5):

The duplicate relationship that is currently there (of the higher viewed one to the lower viewed one) is the correct one.

A merge would be incorrect and problematic.  Mostly because, both have accepted answers and are very slightly different in focus.  If the lower view was merged into the higher viewed one, the disproportionate number of votes in the higher viewed one (accepted answer +160, 82 words) would be much higher ranked than the accepted answer of the lower viewed one (+14, 413 words) (it would be the fourth highest scoring post in the other set of answers).

The merge would do a disservice to the much better and more complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my view, the current state is the right one (with the high-visit question being closed as duplicate of the low-visit question).

To me, the question [Relation between BDD and TDD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111837/relation-between-bdd-and-tdd) has the better answer and by marking [What is the difference between writing test cases for BDD and TDD?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/what-is-the-difference-between-writing-test-cases-for-bdd-and-tdd) as a duplicate, readers of the more often, and thus probably more easily, found question get a trigger that there might be more to investigate.

Having the duplicate link the other way around effectively moves that good answer further away from the readers.